# Removing first 2 items from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't seem to figure out how to take the first 2 out of the list. Here is the question, please, I need help.

Write a function that, when given a list of any number of items, returns the first two items on the list missing their first letter. If the list does not have two items, the function returns "This list has less than two items."

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Are you familiar with how to create and begin to write a python file? If so, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46437995/edit) the question and include any code that you have started to solve the problem, then we can see where you are stuck and help you further. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `missing their first letter`?

Answer (score 3):

```
def somefun(list):
    if len(list) < 2:
        return "This list has less than two Items"
    else:
        first_item = list.pop(0)
        second_item = list.pop(0)
        return "First Item: {}\nSecond Item: {}".format(first_item,second_item)
```

You could pop the items out of the list.

Becareful when using pop, it removes the items from the list, and the items.  remaining become shifted.

For example, take the following list:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
```

The number at index 0 is 1 and the number at index 1 is 2, when I use pop(0) and supply the index, it removes that number, so in this case it removes 1, and the numbers are shifted, so index 0 is 2, index 1 is 3, etc..

Answer (score 1):

```
def somefun(list):
    if len(list) < 2:return "This list has less than two Items"
    else:
        first_item = list[0]
        second_item = list[1]
        del list[1]
        del list[0]
        return "First Item: {}\nSecond Item: {}".format(first_item,second_item)
```

It's pretty easy, Check if the len is less than 2, if it's not then remove 2 first Items and return them...

Also I guess I didn't understand your question fully, ( Returns the first two Items on the List, Missing their first letter ) ? If it's what u want then on the last line instead of `format.(first_item,second_item)` you need to use `format(first_item[1:],second_item[1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

another solution using list slicing and list comprehension

```
items = ['a','b','c','d']

print("\n".join(map(str,items[0:2])) if len(items)>=2 else 'List has less than 2 elements')
```

output:

```
a
b
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by `missing their first letter`, you mean that the items don't begin with an ASCII letter (it's hard to tell if you meant that -- but if so), then this might work as a starting point for you:

```
from string import ascii_letters as letters

out = []
def aFunc(aList):
   if len(aList) < 2: return ['This list has less than two items.',]

   for s in aList:
      s[0] not in letters and out.append(s)
      if len(out) == 2: break

   res = out if len(out) == 2 else ['This list has less than two items.',]
   return res
```

I enclosed your "exception string" in a 1-item list so that you won't have to perform a type-check on the returned result: It will be a list either way and, in fact, if it is length-2 then you have your items; and if it is length-1 then it will simply contain your "excpetion string".

Answer (score 0):

Let a list is created by name List than to remove first two item from the list (provided it contain at least two content than the code is:

```
list.remove(list[0])      #for first item
list.remove(list[0])      #for second item
```

simple and shortcode to delete first 2 item from a list